# Thread waiting on a wait condition in a multiprocess setup is not awakened

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, pthreads, wait

I have a strange problem with using wait conditions and mutexes from pthreads on Linux to do synchronization between processes. Note that this is not between threads in one process only.

My use case is that there's a producer that creates resources (images in my case), saves them to a shared memory area, updates some information about the resource and then signals a waiting consumer. The shared memory and the meta data part works fine, so I'll leave that out, the problem is that the signalling does not work reliably. The use case is simple in that it doesn't matter if the consumer misses one image or two, the producer basically just overwrites one old image if the consumer hasn't had time to read it yet. So the wait condition only needs to handle waking up the consumer, I don't need there to be any resource counts or other data.

Both the producer and consumer have a struct like this:

```
struct EventData {
    pthread_mutex_t mutexHandle;
    pthread_cond_t  conditionHandle;
};
```

A thread in the consumer process sits and waits for something to happen:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &eventData->mutexHandle );
pthread_cond_wait( &eventData->conditionHandle, &eventData->mutexHandle );
thread_mutex_unlock( &eventData->mutexHandle );
```

The producing process does this when it has created an image, saved it into shared memory and is ready to let the consumer grab the image:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &eventData->mutexHandle );
pthread_cond_signal( &eventData->conditionHandle );

// also tried:
//pthread_cond_broadcast( &eventData->conditionHandle );
pthread_mutex_unlock( &eventData->mutexHandle );
```

This looks quite ok to me and it works to some extent. The producer can signal the consumer about 100-1000 times without any issues, the consumer wakes up, grabs the image and shows it, the result being a video that I can see moving. At some point, usually around a few hundred frames, the consumer will freeze in pthread_cond_wait() and never return. The producer still happily creates images, calls pthread_cond_signal() and continues without problems. The consumer has not totally frozen, only the thread that does the pthread_cond_wait(), the rest of the application runs without issue.

So, something causes the signal to get lost when it moves from one thread to another thread in another process. It takes normally 5-20 seconds before the consumer freezes, and the amount of times the waking up works also varies between 100 and 1000 (based on values seen so far).

As mutexes and wait conditions are not trivial to share between processes by default, I've used this setup to create the primitives:

```
    EventData * eventData;

    int fd = open( tmpnam(NULL), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
    if (fd < 0) {
        // failed to open file for event
    }

    if ( ftruncate(fd, sizeof (eventData )) < 0 ) {
        // failed to truncate file
    }

    // setup attributes to allow sharing between processes
    pthread_condattr_init( &conditionAttribute );
    pthread_condattr_setpshared( &conditionAttribute, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED );
    pthread_mutexattr_init( &mutexAttribute );
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared( &mutexAttribute, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED );

    // map memory for the event struct
    eventData = (EventData *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(EventData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close (fd);

    // finally initialize the memory
    pthread_mutex_init( &eventData->mutexHandle, &mutexAttribute );
    pthread_cond_init( &eventData->conditionHandle, &conditionAttribute );
```

The above is done by the party that creates the mutex and wait condition. The name of the file, i.e. tmpnam(NULL) is in reality saved and passed to the other process for opening:

```
    int fd = open( nameOfEventFile, O_RDWR, 0666 );
    if (fd < 0) {
        // failed to open file for event
    }

    eventData = (EventData *) mmap( NULL, sizeof(EventData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
    close( fd );
```

I see no errors here and would like some hint as to what could go wrong, especially as it works some random time.

Comment: Note that in general, you want to use `pthread_cond_wait` in a loop like, `while (!some_condition) pthread_cond_wait(...);`. This should prevent you from waiting for an event that may have already occurred.

Answer (score 1):

And as soon as I had written 95% of the question the error poked me in the eye... I still decied to put it up here along with the fix in case someone else stumbles upon something similar. The part where the mutex and wait conditions are created looks like this:

```
EventData * eventData;

int fd = open( tmpnam(NULL), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
if (fd < 0) {
    // failed to open file for event
}

if ( ftruncate(fd, sizeof (eventData )) < 0 ) {
    // failed to truncate file
}
```

If you look carefully you see that the ftruncate() truncates to the size of the eventData pointer, not the size of struct EventData. So, the one character fix needed here is:

```
if ( ftruncate(fd, sizeof (EventData )) < 0 ) {
    // failed to truncate file
}
```

Stupid bug, indeed.

Comment: A more flexible solution would be to use `sizeof(*eventData)`. So even if the defintion of  `eventData` would change there would be no need to adjust the call to `ftruncate()`.